# The speed of an electrical signal through different mediums

Tags: energy, electrostatics, electricity

This is sort of a bio physics question and it comes in two parts. The first is: what is the speed of an electrical signal through human nervous tissue?

The second part is: what is the speed of an electrical signal through a gold wire that is comparable in length and thickness of a human spinal cord?

Edit: It was remiss of me not to have mentioned that the gold given in this example is for all intents and purposes pure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is related to biology, not physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the speed of an electrical signal through human nervous tissue?

In a regular wire, when you apply a voltage at one end, the wire reacts to that voltage at a very high speed (usually a significant fraction of $c$) due to direct interaction of mobile charges and electric fields.  You can do the same thing to parts of the body and the ionic content will propagate potential (quickly) in a similar manner.

But neurons don't signal that way.  They instead use ion pumps to maintain a potential difference between the interior and exterior of the neuron.  When stimulated properly, the potential changes and the nerve reacts by opening ion channels to propagate the signal.  So although a neuron uses electrical potentials, it's not an "electrical signal" in the same way that a wire transmits one.

Because of this, the speed is much lower, up to 120 m/s according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_conduction_velocity)